# Fitting a glass board with glue or by making holes?

Tags: glass

I want to have a glass board on my wall. It is way too cheaper to buy a piece of etched glass from the local shop and fix it to the wall than buying ready-made glass boards from online stores. My  requirement is 5.5 feet × 3.5 feet borderless. I went to a local shop for the glass and other fittings. They suggested at least 6 mm thick glass and gave me two fitting options.

1. Make 6 holes in the wall and in the glass. Then screw the glass through the holes.
2. Don't make any holes in the glass. Only make holes in the wall and drill some screws in the wall only. Then glue the glass with those screws.

Now which one is safer ? How stable and reliable these glues are ? Will making holes make the glass crack after few years ?

**Edit**
I'll not need to glue or make the holes by myself. The glass shop will send someone to my place to do the fittings. And they will not charge me if something breaks at the time of fittings. I need to choose what type of fittings I want.

Comment: This may be a better fit on diy.SE or possibly Arts and Crafts.SE.  I don't think it needs a lifehack.

Comment: Hi Neel Basu, Welcome to lifehacks.SE. You have already have a good solution for your budget and decor. All you require is conventional means of attaching it where you want. That's probably better suited to either of Chenmunka's suggestions.

Comment: What are the conventional means of fitting a glass (borderless) ? Also can anyone migrate this question to an appropriate SE ?

Comment: I wouldn't use adhesive because you will see it through the glass even it it's clear.  Consider mounting it with mirror mounts.  They are small pieces that grab the edge of the glass.  You screw through those into studs.  They aren't very noticeable.  A variation is a full length lucite "bracket" top and bottom.  It's "L" shaped to fit against the edge with a tiny lip to grab the glass.  You screw through that.  Since it's full length, uniform, and clear, it's not very noticeable.  You can drill through glass if you're careful, but it's easy to break the glass, or have it crack later.

Comment: I won't need to make the holes. They will. And they won't charge me if it breaks then. And regarding glue, I don't know what type of glue they will use. But they said that the glue is strong to hold the glass for years and the glass is eched so the glue will not be visible. They asked me to decide what fittings I want them to use.